# Showing data from a string on the localStorage and show it in a pop up out of the app

Tags: javascript, html, json, html5-canvas, local-storage

I have been dealing with this particular situation. I have a form in which the user can put some data and save it. He can do that several times creating a record of similar items. The app creates a string with this data and saves it in the localStorage. The user is able to retrieve the data on a page created with an accordion system where he can see it separately just as he typed before. Now I need to get some data from the LocalStorage to show it in a page which is out of the DOM of the app.

This is the **js** controller code where I want to show the data:

```
    define(["app",
    "js/clientModel",
    "js/preViewer/preViewerView"],
     function(app, Client, preView) {

var client = null;
var payment = null;
//var $ = Dom7;
var state = {
    isNew: false
};
var bindings = [];

function init(query){
    //console.log(query.idP);
    var clients = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("f7Clients"));
    if (query && query.id) {
        client = new Client(_.find(clients, { id: query.id }));
        //console.log(client);
        if (query && query.idP) {
            payment = _.find(client.payments, { id: query.idP });
            //console.log(payment);
        }
    }

            /*find the client by ci and load its data into client var
    var tempClientId = sessionStorage.getItem('tempClientId');
    var client;
    async function loadClientJsonToObject(id){
        let clients = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('f7Clients'));
        await clients.forEach((p)=>{
            if(p.id === id){
                client = p;
            }
        });

        return newClients;
    }*/

    preView.render({
        model: client,
        payment: payment,
        bindings: bindings,
        state: state,
        apps: client.getFullAppointments2(),
    });

    console.log('preViewerController  init()  fnc done...');
}

function closePage() {
    if (!state.isNew) {
        app.router.load('client', {id: client.id});
    }
    else {
        app.mainView.loadPage('client.html?id=' + client.id, false);
    }
    app.f7.closeModal();
}


return {
    init: init
};
});
```

And this is how my **localStorage** looks like:

```
[{
"id": "d71b8519-3e89-4056-fd1a-8f1e0240cfe4", "hasPic": false, "picId": 2, "picSrc": "", "picFile": [], "createdOn": "2022-01-08T02:38:12.960Z", "firstName": "Fulano Menganejo Ciclanejo", "company": "La Fábrica", "mobile": "+53555555", "phone": "+5372222222", "email": "fulano@nauta.cu", "address": "La calle #100 e/ La Otra y Aquella, El Pueblo, La Ciudad, La Provincia, El País", "nit": "345748368353", "job": "Barrendero", "lapse": "", "gender": "M", "whatsapp": "https://www.dagikeqeqomy.me.uk", "telegram": "https://www.dagikeqeqomy.me.uk", 

"payments": [ {
"id": "1", "ldate": "18/11/-1982 12:00 am", "lapse": "Octubre", "di": "42000", "myp": "910", "pcincome": "1", "pcbr": "Dolorem cupidatat ab", "pcvs": "3", "pcvsbr": "Est eiusmod asperior", "wf": "82", "wfbr": "Ut iusto magni sunt ", "ss": "69", "ssbr": "Nihil laboris assume", "pi": "69", "pibr": "Autem eiusmod aut ab", "fee": "1", "feebr": "In aut duis doloribu", "lp": "4", "lpbr": "Culpa consequatur d", "fp": "61", "fpbr": "Officia ea ullam eli", "pss": "43", "pssbr": "Odio harum voluptas ", "ass": "55", "assbr": "Non ut ad exercitati", "pitcp": "99", "pitcpbr": "Magni obcaecati culp", "doc": "71", "docbr": "Officiis est sint e", "pia": "73", "piabr": "Officia in iusto ver", "pv": "29", "pvbr": "Sint quas explicabo", "car": "31", "carbr": "Eum velit reprehend", "ship": "69", "shipbr": "Tenetur aliqua Volu", "total": "760"
},{
"id": "2", "ldate": "27/06/-1982 12:00 am", "lapse": "Mayo", "di": "58000", "myp": "560", "pcincome": "919", "pcbr": "Et et reiciendis ita", "pcvs": "65", "pcvsbr": "Beatae sunt dolorem ", "wf": "95", "wfbr": "Fugiat pariatur Eli", "ss": "30", "ssbr": "Ea totam cupidatat m", "pi": "21", "pibr": "Voluptates enim eius", "fee": "63", "feebr": "Consequat Pariatur", "lp": "24", "lpbr": "Eos et nobis possim", "fp": "36", "fpbr": "Illum dolor deserun", "pss": "75", "pssbr": "Debitis sunt quia po", "ass": "46", "assbr": "Fugiat magni et et p", "pitcp": "39", "pitcpbr": "Sint totam a minus c", "doc": "90", "docbr": "Enim tenetur Nam und", "pia": "82", "piabr": "Obcaecati laborum I", "pv": "28", "pvbr": "Tenetur in cupiditat", "car": "78", "carbr": "Sit dolores ipsam ve", "ship": "46", "shipbr": "Voluptatum qui aut d", "total": "1737"
}]
```

}]

And this is the **page** where I need to show the data. The specific items to show are mobile and email:

[image]

This is my **html** code:

```
    <div class="popup">
<div class="view view-popup navbar-fixed">
    <div class="navbar">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="left"></div>
            <div class="center sliding">VISTA PREVIA</div>
            <div class="right"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="page client-page">
        <div class="page-content">
            <div class="content-block">
             <div class="list-block">
                                    <a onclick="getpng()" aria-label="Guardar"><div onclick="history.go(-1);" class="float-buttonr"><i class="btn icon simbicon-download" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></a>
                                    <a class="link close-popup" aria-label="Cancelar"><div class="float-buttonl"><i class="btn icon simbicon-close-b" aria-hidden="true"></i></div></a>
                                    <div class="content-block report"><br/>
                                        <div class="content-block-title">Comprobante de pago de la <i class="icon simbicon-onat" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title-range">CLIENTE:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{model.firstName}}</div></div>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title-range">NIT:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{model.nit}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">Fecha:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.ldate}}&nbsp;</div>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title-range">Periodo:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.lapse}}</div></div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Ingreso declarado:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.di}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>
                                        {{#if payment.pcvs}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0114022 ventas y servicios:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.pcvs}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.pcvsbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.rent}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0200822 Arrendamiento:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.rent}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.rentbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.ps}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">02001022 Servicios públicos:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.ps}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.psbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.pitcp}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0510122 ingresos personales (TCP):<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.pitcp}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.pitcpbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.sr}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0510522 Regimén simplificado (PN):<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.sr}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.srbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.pipp}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0520322 Ingresos per. (ret. y PP):<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.pipp}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.pippbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.pirtcp}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0520522 Ingresos per. (ret. TCP):<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.pirtcp}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.pirtcpbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.pic}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0530102 Ingresos per. (SC):<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.pic}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.picbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.pia}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0530122 Ingresos per (agr.):<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.pia}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.piabr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.pi}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0530222 Ingresos per. (liq. a.):<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.pi}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.pibr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.pie}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0530322 Ingresos pers. eve.:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.pie}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.piebr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.piec}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0530422 Ingresos per. (CE):<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.piec}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.piecbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.wf}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0610322 Fuerza de trabajo:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.wf}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.wfbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.wr}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0620102 Recursos forestales:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.wr}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.wrbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.bay}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0620702 Uso y exp. de Bahías:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.bay}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.baybr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.pv}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0710122 Propiedad o vivienda:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.pv}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.pvbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.ul}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0710402 Tierras ociosas:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.ul}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.ulbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.ship}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0710522 Embarcaciones:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.ship}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.shipbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.car}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0710622 Transporte terrestre:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.car}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.carbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.he}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0720122 Herencias:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.he}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.hebr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.doc}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0730122 Impuestos sobre doc.:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.doc}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.docbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.ass}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0810232 Seguridad soc. artes p.:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.ass}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.assbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.pss}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0810432 Seguridad soc. usufruc.:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.pss}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.pssbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.ss}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0820132 Seguridad social:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.ss}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.ssbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.sss}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0820332 Seguridad social (mar.):<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.sss}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.sssbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.sgn}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">0900122 Anuncios y propaganda:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.sgn}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.sgnbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.or}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">1010602 Otros derechos:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.or}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.orbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.bld}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">1020102 Licencia de const.:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.bld}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.bldbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.wood}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">1030102 Multa forestal:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.wood}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.woodbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.fee}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">1030122 Multas y contravenciones:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.fee}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.feebr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.hab}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">1030202 Multas medio ambiente:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.hab}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.habbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.lp}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">1060122 Recargo por mora:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.lp}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.lpbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.fp}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">1060522 Recargo por apremio:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.fp}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.fpbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.ld}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">1060922 Aplazamiento de deuda T:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.ld}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.ldbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        {{#if payment.gft}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title">1240102 Donaciones:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.gft}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Referencia bancaria:<div class="payment">&nbsp;{{payment.gftbr}}</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>{{/if}}
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Total pagado:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.total}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>
                                        <div class="item-title payment-title payment-title-last">Comisión de servicio:<div class="payment">&nbsp;${{payment.myp}} CUP</div></div><br/>
                                        <br/>
                                        <div class="item-title" style="text-align:center;margin-bottom:5px;"><i class="icon simbicon-arrowdown"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Ante cualquier duda o aclaración&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="icon simbicon-arrowdown"></i></div>
                                        <div class="item-content" style="border-bottom:1px solid #9f9f9f;border-top:1px solid #9f9f9f;">
                                            <div class="item-media"><i class="icon simbicon-contact-s"></i></div>
                                            <div class="item-inner" style="border:none;">
                                                <div style="flex-direction:column;">
                                                    <div class="item-media"><i class="icon simbicon-mobile-s"></i><div class="payment">+53 54749683</div></div>
                                                    <div class="item-media"><i class="icon simbicon-sms-s"></i><div class="payment">yadian.palacio@nauta.cu</div></div>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br/>
                                        <div class="payment-title-last"  style="display:flex;;flex-direction: row;"><img src="img/blank.svg"/>
                                            <div style="margin-left:40px;"><br/><br/><br/>
                                            <div class="payment" style="border-top:1px solid #9f9f9f;padding-top:5px;">Firma del Gestor</div><br/><br/><br/><br/>
                                            <div class="payment" style="border-top:1px solid #9f9f9f;padding-top:5px;">Firma del Cliente</div>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <br/><br/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
            </div> <!--content block-->
        </div> <!--page content-->
    </div> <!--page-->
</div> <!--view popup-->
</div> <!--popup-->
```

¿What do I need?
To call the localStorage, get the values for email and mobile and show them at the end of the page (see image for reference). I think that will solve the problem but I failed on the try. ¿Any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is in the object you call in `html2canvas`. I made a codesandbox where I use an accordion and capture the open element to render it on a canvas.

The steps are:

1. Get the panel that is open
2. Get the panel dimensions to resize the canvas and clean the canvas
3. Paint on the canvas
4. Download image

I leave below the most important function

```
function getScreenshot() {
  if (child) {
    const item = document.getElementById(child);
    var canvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");
    canvas.width = item.clientWidth;
    canvas.height = item.clientHeight;
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    html2canvas(item).then((canvas) => {
      ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);

      //DOWNLOAD
      var link = document.createElement("a");
      link.download = "filename.png";
      link.href = canvas.toDataURL();
      link.click();
    });
  } else {
    console.log("PLEASE, OPEN SECTION");
  }
}
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/html2canvas-download-accordion-perkb) (Open the codesandbox in a full tab so you can see that the files are downloaded)

Comment: I have been playing around with your code and it works as is but it's breaking my app when trying to reproduce it within my code. The issue is that my html is not a static page with accordion feature but a page which loads the data fron the localStorage. And I can't use a canvas to show the captured image, what I need is to actually save it to the file system.